# On taking Islamic symbols into tнė bathroom

Tags: halal-haram

I take my phone everywhere including tнė toilet
My question is, is it haraam to do so if my phone’s lock screen is tнė shahaadah.

Answer (score 1):

Most scholars take screen as form of light and not as firm object. And when screen is off it is not even in that form so yes you can take phone with you and it is more useful to have islamic data in phone than having phone otherwise. But in any case it won't be recommended to read or play or use phone in toilet.